# UIWebView stuck at the second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am working on an iOS app that user can pick an email from inbox list, and view it on the next page (there's a UIWebView to serve the content).

Here's what I am observing: The first time I pick the email and it shows up on the second page pretty fast. However, if I navigate back and choose to view the email again, it takes a very long time to get `webViewDidFinishLoad:` called on the second page.

I saw the following message in console:

```
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): 
delegate (webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

As soon as this message is printed, the content is rendered on WebView.

What I don't understand is, this always happen at the second time of using webview to show HTML content. There's no local cache for files/resources, and there's no network issues.

Please point me where I should look at for this issue. Thanks!

---- Update ----

During my random attempts, I found removing this line:

`self.webView.delegate = self;`

will make the issue gone. This makes me feel even more confusing. Why making self to be the delegate could cause such issue?

---- Update 2 ----

I found the culprit is a flatten html method I called after webview loaded the html. **If I remove the NSHTMLTextDocumentType it's all good**, but I don't understand why:

```
+ (NSString *) stripHtmlSchema: (NSString *)htmlString
{
    NSString *flatString = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                            options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                      NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]}
                                                 documentAttributes:nil
                                                              error:nil] string];
    return flatString;
}
```

---- Final Update ----

Figured out the issue. `[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData` was taking too long to execute, so blocked everything.

Comment: Do you use any javascript code in your webview? 
The docs state that 

"JavaScript execution time is limited to 10 seconds for each top-level entry point. If your script executes for more than 10 seconds, the web view stops executing the script"

Comment: @MathiasKogler thanks for your reply. There's no javascript execution. And I don't understand how it can work for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. `[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData` was taking too long to execute, so blocked everything.